# Converting fetchall list of tuples into strings? Python3

Tags: python

I'm using the SELECT command on sqlite3 and then with fetchall i'm reading the list of tuples... And i'm getting:

```
[(1, 'Pencil', '99', 25.0, 30.0, 5.0), (2, 'Marker', '40', 30.0, 20.0, -10.0)]
```

How can i convert this into:

```
[('1', 'Pencil', '99', '25.0', '30.0', '5.0'), (2, 'Marker', '40', '30.0', '20.0', '-10.0')]
```

What if there were more tuples in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `map` to accomplish that:

```
a = [(1, 'Pencil', '99', 25.0, 30.0, 5.0), (2, 'Marker', '40', 30.0, 20.0, -10.0)]

a_new = [tuple(map(str, i)) for i in a]

>>> print(a_new)
[('1', 'Pencil', '99', '25.0', '30.0', '5.0'), ('2', 'Marker', '40', '30.0', '20.0', '-10.0')]
```

You can quickly try it here: [DEMO](http://repl.it/oUp)